# How to correctly install python3 and virtualenv on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, homebrew

I start to learn Django framework so I need to install latest python, pip, virtualenv and django packets on my mac. 
I try to do it with brew, but I got some strange behavior.

At first, python3 installed not in /usr/bin/ but in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework directory:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

It is strange for me, because every tutorial tells about /usr/bin/python37 and nothing about /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
Is this okay?

After that I made `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` and got this answer:

```
The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Okay, I made uninstall and install with -H sudo flag:

```
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-16.4.3
```

But when I try to make a virtual environment, I got

```
$ virtualenv venv
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

Checking virtualenv location:

```
$ which virtualenv
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenv
```

Why /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/? 
And why it searches for virtualenv in /usr/local/bin/virtualenv?
Coding on Macos is always so painful?

Comment: [https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file)  add this to your ~/.bashrc file and this too: `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. One more question - do I also need virtualenvwrapper installation? Because I have no virtualenvwrapper.sh script...

Comment: Also I have no $HOME/.virtualenvs in my homefolder.

Comment: Have removed all pip packets, pip itself, python, even homebrew. Reinstalled brew, python3. Used this manual: https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/ Now virtualenv works well. So will try to install django and test it

Comment: Yes, perfect! Question can be closed. Thank you for answer anyway.

Answer (score 25):

Instead of using brew you can simply use "venv".

To create a virtual environment you can run -->

```
python3 -m venv environment_name
```

Example: If you want to create an virtual environment for django with name django_env

```
python3 -m venv django_env
```

"-m" flag checks for sys.path and executes main module.

**Activation of Virtual Environment :**

```
source django_env/bin/activate
```

**Deactivation :**

```
deactivate
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Python3 Virtualenv Setup

Requirements:

- Python3
- Pip3

```sh
$ brew install python3 #upgrade
```

Pip3 is installed with Python3

**Installation**

To install virtualenv via pip run:

```sh
$ pip3 install virtualenv
```

**Usage**

Creation of virtualenv:

```sh
$ virtualenv -p python3 <desired-path>
```

Activate the virtualenv:

```sh
$ source <desired-path>/bin/activate
```

Deactivate the virtualenv:

```sh
$ deactivate
```

---

You can see more about the `Homebrew` on the [official page](https://brew.sh).

Comment: copypasta from https://gist.github.com/pandafulmanda/730a9355e088a9970b18275cb9eadef3

Answer (score 0):

Just follow as below:

1. $ pip install virtualenv
   Once installed, you can create a virtual environment with:
2. $ virtualenv [directory]
   On  MacOS, we activate our virtual environment with the source command. If you created your venv in the myvenv directory, the command would be
3. $ source myvenv/bin/activate